# How to sort a jSON file alphabetically and assign them to the corresponding letter to use sectionIndexTitlesForTableView/ sectionForSectionIndexTitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

This is my first time asking a question here, so please excuse my lack of writing etiquette.
I have a jSON data file which looks like this:

```
[ {
"category": "Feline",
"text": "CAT",
"definition": "Meow"   },   
{
"category": "Mammal",
"text": "DOG",
"definition": "Bark"   },  
{
"category": "Insect",
"text": "ANT ",
"definition": "buzz"   },   
{
"category": "Insect'",
"text": "MOSQUITO ",
"definition": "buzz"   },
{
"category": "Number'",
"text": "10",
"definition": "ten"   } 
]
```

I am importing it as follows, the **dataList** is a NSMutableArray, I am also confused if using the MutableArray is good or if I should be using NSDictionary?:

```
-(void)readDataFromFile {

    NSString * filePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json"];

    NSError * error;
    NSString* fileContents =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }
    self.dataList = (NSMutableArray *)[NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                options:0 error:NULL]; 

}
```

I would like to sort the JSON data alphabetically according to **'text'**
and also I am using sections and index list. I mainly followed https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/ tutorial.

I am confused on how to sort the JSON data and also divide them into sections of alphabets and also iOS contacts accounts for numbers by putting them under '#' section.
How do i accomplish that as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out [UILocalizedIndexedCollation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalizedindexedcollation), which is designed for that purpose (though it's a little cumbersome to use).

Comment: How can I use a JSON file with this though?

Comment: "the dataList is a NSMutableArray", not after `self.dataList = (NSMutableArray *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:NULL];` Should be a `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

> In the below code i've made an 2D array of 27 elements(1 for numeric
>   and 26 for alphabets) and then placed the value according to the
>   string initial character. This piece of code worked for me.Hope so it
>   will work for you too :)

```
        for (int section = 0; section < 27; section++)
        {
            [arrSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
        }
        for (NSDictionary *item in SampleDictionary)
        {
            NSString *KeyValue = [item[@"DictionaryKEy"] capitalizedString];                    
             *//In your case its Text*
            int ascii = (int)[KeyValue characterAtIndex:kZero];

            if (ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90)
            {
                [arrSections[(ascii - 64)] addObject:item];
            }
            else
            {
                [arrSections[0] addObject:item];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using a constant kZero for 0 is ridiculous.